# Adding FireBase SDK to my project causes jcenter.bintray.com error host name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-2.2

[image]

I have been searching for a while now and couldn't possibly find the solution for this. I am so confused now. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this could be the result of a misconfigured dns or a mitm proxy:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=jcenter.bintray.com

Would be interesting to know what the real issue was.

Comment: Probably, because when I tried using jcenter.bintray.com using other ISP it worked. I also spoke to some friend which uses the same ISP that I was using, apparently he's also having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using other url rather than jcenter.bintray.com

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}
```